# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, exception, awt-eventqueue

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpcap in java.library.path

is the error I keep getting, do I need to add a path to jcap? or change my configurations?

Comment: I guess you must add jpcap to your CLASSPATH

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz The CLASSPATH is only for Java libraries (class files or JAR files); not for native libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that Java cannot find a native library. If you're on Windows, it's looking for `jpcap.dll`; if it's Linux or OS X, it's probably `jpcap.so`. You need to set the system property `java.library.path` to include the directory that contains the library.

For example, if you have `jpcap.dll` in a directory named `C:\MyProject`:

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:\MyProject com.mypackage.MyProgram
```